# Parting ways with uncountable choice

Tags: set-theory, axiom-of-choice, foundations

Please forgive me if this question has already been asked in one form or another (in which case, it would suffice to provide the link to the corresponding post which has the answer).

My question: What would happen if we parted ways with uncountable choice? In other words, imagine working within the fragment of ZFC in which you have all of the usual axioms at your disposal (including *countable* choice), but you throw out the uncountable form of the axiom of choice. What sorts of problems might arise while working within this system? What are some non-trivial examples of theorems which can be "saved" (in the sense that they only required countable choice to begin with) and theorems which "break" (in the sense that their proofs explicitly depended on uncountable choice)?

Comment: Some things get slightly more annoying; for example in number theory use is occasionally made of a highly non-canonical isomorphism $\overline{\mathbb{Q}_p} \cong \mathbb{C}$ which requires uncountable choice to construct. Overall I don't think it's a big deal (e.g. in this case instead of using the entire isomorphism you can construct a countable fragment of it).

Comment: You can find a discussion of this example here: https://mathoverflow.net/a/22944

Comment: This is too broad of a question. The axiom of choice affects almost every area of mathematics. Consider looking at  “Consequences of the Axiom of Choice” by Howard and Rubin for a thorough answer. “The Axiom of Choice” by Jech is also a good introductory source if you want to dig into some of the methodology of proving independence results.

Comment: One interesting consequence is that if $\scr A$ is an uncountable collection of sets, each with more than one element, then you cannot prove $\prod_{A \in \scr A}A \ne \emptyset$. Indeed, the claim that all such products are not empty is equivalent to the axiom of choice.